# Can I send http/2 request with OkHttp over NPN Negotiation?

Tags: okhttp, http2, alpn, npn

I notice that OkHttp support h2 over ALPN in Android 5.0+.

From [some article](http://www.kafsemo.org/2015/01/08_talking-HTTP-2.html),I learned that we can use NPN Negotiation for http/2 request.

Can I send http/2 request with OkHttp over NPN Negotiation?

So that it's possible to support h2 on android 4.1+ with better network performance :-D

Comment: I found the OkHttp change log. Did Okhttp dropped NPN support on version 2.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We dropped NPN support. ALPN is the future.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :-D